# How do I query a specific nested field alongside the a field outside the nest in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have some documents that have the following _source:

```
Document 1
"class":{
  "students": [
{
 "name": "Hello"
},
{
 "name": "John"
}
],
"Teacher" : "Ryan"

Document 2
"class":{
  "students": [
{
 "name": "Kathy"
},
{
 "name": "Ryan"
}
],
"Teacher" : "Matthew"

Document 3
"class":{
  "students": [
{
 "name": "Ryan"
},
{
 "name": "Ryan"
}
],
"Teacher" : "Smith"
```

I want to find the relevance scores of each of these documents where any matches to the "Teacher" field is boosted by 2 and then the following is prioritized by the relevance score of the matches to "ryan" in the name field. While the boost to the "Teacher" is working as expected (Document 1 has the highest score), the other documents have the same relevance scores (Document 2 and 3) even though they contain a different number of "names" matching "ryan".

This is my current query

```
  "query":{
    "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "should": [
                     {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "class.students",
                        "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "class.students.name": {
                                  "query": "Ryan",
                                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                        }
              },
              {
              "match": {
                "class.Teacher": {
                  "boost" : 2,
                  "query": "Ryan",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              }
          }
               
                  ]
               }
            }
            ]
}
}
```

I tried `score_mode:avg` and max but this didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?